# Mongoose populate possible null field

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to use the populate method on a field that might be null. In my example, I want to populate the *jobId* field.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58867d5406912821a89c9f5f"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("588667e0efdb7802902090d0"),
    "locationId" : ObjectId("58866fcfefdb7802902090d8"),
    "quantity" : 2,
    "dimensions" : "2",
    "category" : "Food",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588f535fd9e16c31005fe944"),
    "jobId" : "",
    "locationId" : ObjectId("588761ecd947971c540bc460"),
    "quantity" : 3,
    "dimensions" : "2",
    "category" : "Soupe",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

However because *jobId* is an empty string on the second object, I get the following error

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Job\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "",
"path": "_id"
```

So I was wondering if it was possible to populate if *jobId* is not null and otherwise leave it unchange.

Thank you

Comment: why are you storing an empty string? Dont store anything in the schema in case of empty string. Then you will be able to populate without any casting error

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will give it a try!

Comment: can you show how you are saving these documents? Then may be i can help you save it in a proper way so that it doesn't throw any such errors

Comment: I was storing '' for empty fields, I changed from '' to null and the casting error was gone. Thanks @RaviShankarBharti